How can I automatically add a user to a Microsoft Teams group or channel using their email address without using the Graph API?
I'm working on an automation task where I need to automatically add a user to a Microsoft Teams group or channel as soon as I retrieve their email address. I want to write a script or use a tool to achieve this, but I would like to avoid using the Microsoft Graph API directly.
Is there an alternative method to accomplish this? Ideally, I'd like to use a script, or any other automation tool that can integrate with Microsoft Teams and allow me to add users by email. Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated

Alternatively, you can use Powershell to add users. Please refer to these docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/add-teamchanneluser?view=teams-ps,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.teams/add-mgchatmember?view=graph-powershell-1.0

You can use azure logic app. This resource is prefect for you case. build-in logic app connnector for Microsoft Teams help in codeless.

I agree with @Meghana-MSFT, you can make use of PowerShell to add a user to a Microsoft Teams group or channel using their email address by making use of Microsoft Teams PowerShell module.
Get Teams:
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Get-Team 

To add user to a Microsoft Teams group, use the below command:
Add-TeamUser -GroupId GroupID -User User@XXX.onmicrosoft.com

Get-TeamUser -GroupId GroupID



Note that: Adding the user to the group will take between 24 and 48 hours to appear within the Teams client.

To add user to the Microsoft Teams Specific channel, make use of below command:
Get the channel details
Get-TeamChannel -GroupId GroupID


And make use of command to add user to the Microsoft Teams channel,:
Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId GroupID -DisplayName "Ruk First Private Channel" -User User@XXX.onmicrosoft.com



Users can be added only to private channels.
To add a user as a member to a channel, they must first be a member of the team.
To add a user an owner of a channel, they need to first be a member of the channel.

References:
Add-TeamUser (MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell) | Microsoft 
Add-TeamChannelUser (MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell) | Microsoft 
